# Any way in Java to build objects with custom field names?

Tags: java

```java
MyResult result = myApi.regex("(?<left>\d+) + (?<right>\d+)").match("12 + 5");
assert Integer.parseInt(result.left) == 12;
```

Is there any way to get some code like the above working?

I'll use the example of regex named capture groups; can the user specify the names of the capture groups, and access them later, and it's all subject to compile-time static analysis and correction checking?

So no runtime

```java
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<left>\d+) + (?<right>\d+)");
MatchResult result = regex.match("12 + 5");
result.group("lft") // RuntimeException no group named lft
```

type of errors, because all the information to do useful static analysis will always already exist in the source code directly in my case.

So for example, in the first code snippet,

```java
MyResult result = myApi.regex("(?<left>\d+) + (?<right>\d+)").match("12 + 5");
assert Integer.parseInt(result.left) == 12;
```

`MyResult` would be a class that specifies public `left` and `right` fields, because those were the names of the capture groups specified in the regex.

I think I can't even do it via any kind of binding in Java, e.g.

```cs
string left, right;
Regex regex = myApi.capture("\d+", out left).literal(" + ").capture("\d+", out right);
regex.match("12 + 5");
assert left.equals("12");
```

is also not a type of API you can build in Java (afaik).

The best I can come up with is something where the user needs to make their own class and do the parsing themselves:

```
public class SumRegex extends MyApi.Regex {
    String left, right;

    doMatch() {
        left = capture("\d+");
        literal(" + ");
        right = capture("\d+");
        end();
    }
}
```

But this is too verbose, unwieldy.

So what would be a good solution? How can you enable static analysis for the users of your library that is to do with string building and parsing?

Comment: This requires a level of compiler plugins that java simply does not offer. Build an IDE plugin, that's the simplest way to get what you want (and is still _very_ complicated).

Comment: @rzwitserloot you mean Java can't support this, you have to add additional static analysis of strings themselves to your IDE?

Comment: no, because at compile time your regex is just a string, the compiler has no idea what groups are there.

Comment: I guess you can try building the source, and then compile the class, during runtime.  Maybe, not.

Comment: I could only suggest 1) write unit tests and run then during CI, that would prevent non-working code from being merged 2) custom AnnotationProcessor that would check code at a compile time

Comment: @njzk2 it doesn't have to be that the format string is specified entirely as a string, just that the user is in control of the bound names and where they are represented within a string (e.g. the last code block might be half a step in that direction)

Comment: @G.Domozhirov how would you use AnnotationProcessor for this?

Comment: @minseong nevermind actually ;) with custom AnnotationProcessor and @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE) you have access to the source code. So you are able to write checks being given regex and subsequent lines of code. It won't help create object with custom fields, like `result.left` but it helps to check during annotation processing (which is done during compile time) whether `result["left"]` is valid. Also it requires putting annotation to all methods you want to examine. Implementation also probably would be tricky. Not sure if it's worthy

Comment: @G.Domozhirov that's very interesting! But you're right it's also a lot of work. I'm also most hopeful about being able to expose objects with custom fields compared to the rest, for ease/convenience of the library user...

Comment: @minseong Usually to provide users with handy classes we use code generation with custom plugin. Plugin takes some input, like data model or regex string in your example, and generates java data classes. Not sure if it is applicable in your case

Comment: @G.Domozhirov Standard APs cannot see anything beyond signatures. There are ways to do this (they can also see constants, but `Pattern.compile("....")` isn't a constant).

Comment: I have reconsidered my earlier point that APs just can't do this. yes, they can. I've written an answer expounding on what it would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an Annotation Processor (AP). This has a ton of warts, so let me first expand on those before you commit to doing this:

- You have to save the file that defines the regex, run the build, and only then can you *use* the regex you designed. Vs. e.g. adding a method someplace, and then switching to another source file, where you can use it immediately. (As in, the IDE knows its there). Eclipse in particular does have internal AP support and can run them on its own after you save the file, but this is tricky in different manners.
- Because the AP needs to be run by IDEs *and* build tools, the version of java you compile your AP with is tricky.
- Error reporting of APs running in IDEs isn't great.
- Testing APs is notoriously hard.
- The AP API is not exactly simple.
- Trying to manage the results of incremental compilation is difficult. Either you do it (high learning curve), or you leave it out, which is at least an option here, but it does mean that *deleting* a regex definining source file *does not* remove the actual regex engine class that the AP made.
- Different runners (`javac`, `ecj`, eclipse (and therefore, VSCode because it uses eclipse as a language server for java), intellij, and so on) implement the AP API in slightly different ways. You have to test on all of it. At least javac and eclipse if you want the support to be good).
- Generally the AP itself has to be an entirely separate project.

If you're okay with all of that, the end result once you've written this AP is that you write something like:

```java
@Regexify("(?<left>\d+) + (?<right>\d+)")
public interface MyRegexDef {}
```

and compile it. The result of doing this (because your AP processor can see that and take steps accordingly), is that this class just 'appears' (you don't write it - your AP generated it, it just starts existing after one compilation run):

```java
// Generated by AP
public final class MyRegex {
  private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?<left>\d+) + (?<right>\d+)");

  public static final List<MyRegex> find(String in) {
    var m = PATTERN.matcher(in);
    var out = new ArrayList<MyRegex>();
    while (m.find()) {
      out.add(m.group("left"), m.group("right"));
null;
    }
    return out;
  }

  public static final MyRegex match(String in) {
    var m = PATTERN.matcher(in);
    return m.matches() ? new MyRegex(m.group("left", m.group("right")) : null;
  }

  private final String left;
  private final String right;

  public String getLeft() { return left; }
  public String getRight() { return left; }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null || other.getClass() != MyRegex.class) return false;
    return ((MyRegex) other).left.equals(left) && ((MyRegex) other).right.equals(right);
    // really should also check null v null
  }

  @Override public int hashCode() {
    return left.hashCode() * 31 + right.hashCode();
    // deal with nulls better
  }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return "MyRegex[Left: " + left + " Right: " + right + "]";
  }

  private MyRegex(String left, String right) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }
}

// you get the idea - you can make this look however you want it to look.
```

in addition if the regex is e.g. invalid (mismatched `(` for example), you'd get a *write time* error, as in, a red wavy underline would appear under the regex string in `MyRegexDef` and the `MyRegex` file is not generated at all.

If this sounds like what you want - writing a complete AP tutorial is beyond the scope of SO, but the above outlays what would happen if you spent the time to learn how that works.

Comment: Thanks! That's very cool, and seems to be the only way to do what my question asks for in Java right?

Comment: Do you think that this is a good idea in general? Would you or normal Java devs find an API that lets you write the first code block friendly, or too alien/unusual to like using it?

Comment: [This oft-quoted source of zen-like programmer guidelines](https://xkcd.com/1205/) should be relevant to answer the question. If you go through all that effort, do, please, open source it :)